# Indentation with beamer fontspec and alltt

Tags: beamer, xetex, indentation, fontspec, verbatim

The following document mangles the indentation of the second line of the alltt (the pipe/bar character does not occur under the equals of the previous line).

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
This is some preliminary text

\begin{alltt}
  Hol_datatype`ord = End of num
                   | Plus of ord \(\times\) num \(\times\) ord`
\end{alltt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I do not scale to 14pt as the beamer option, or if I do not use fontspec, the problem goes away.  I do want to use fontspec, but would happily consider some other way of scaling the size of everything in the presentation

Answer (score 2):

The Latin Modern Mono fonts set the interword space with stretchability and shrinkability, which I believe is wrong. Since your second line is overlong with respect to the line width, TeX tries to squeeze it using the interword space shrinkability and it succeeds because this component is non zero.

It's easy to correct it:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setmonofont[WordSpace={1,0,0}]{Latin Modern Mono}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
This is some preliminary text

\begin{alltt}
  Hol_datatype`ord = End of num
                   | Plus of ord \(\times\) num \(\times\) ord`
\end{alltt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The key `WordSpace` takes three numbers as value, which are the factors by which to multiply the default interword space, the interword space stretch and shrink respectively.

Comment: I'll have to install Latin Modern Mono someway or another to test this (I recall a question about this already), but it certainly looks plausible, thanks!  If I use "American Typewriter" as my monofont, I still get

Comment: @MichaelNorrish With `\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}` you are already using Latin Modern Mono, which is predefined by `fontspec` as associated to the `EUx` encoding (x=1 or 2, depending if XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used) and `lmtt` family name.

Comment: Sure, but I can't just write `\fontspec{Latin Modern Mono}`; my `xelatex` complains about it. More significantly, I can't reproduce your fix with either "Latin Modern Mono" or "Andale Mono".  Could this be a problem with the fact that I'm still on TeXLive11 on my Mac?

Comment: @MichaelNorrish Upgrade as soon as possible. In these two years thare have been numerous fixes and enhancements.